# Salesforce REST API: Session expired or invalid: INVALID_SESSION_ID

Tags: apex, rest-api, authentication

**Background**

I am trying to access the Salesforce Reporting REST API.

```
public with sharing class SalesforceReportApi {

    private final static String REPORTS_RESOURCE = '/services/data/v44.0/analytics/reports/';

    private static HttpResponse execute(String method, String restResource) {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        request.setMethod(method);
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint + restResource);
        request.setTimeout(120000); // 2 Minutes

        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');    
        request.setHeader('Content-Type',  'application/json'); 
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());       
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        request.setCompressed(false); 

        HttpResponse httpResponse = new Http().send(request);

        return httpResponse;
    }

    private static String endpoint {
        get { 
            return URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm(); 
        }
    }

    public static MatrixReport getMatrixReport(Id reportId) {

        HttpResponse response = execute(HttpMethod.GET, REPORTS_RESOURCE + reportId);

        return (MatrixReport) JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), MatrixReport.class);
    }
}
```

The request produced is:

> Method: GET
>   URL: https://x--x.cs83.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/analytics/reports/XXXX

But I am getting this error:

> {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}

I thought that since the recent release using `URL.getOrgDomainUrl()` meant to access the REST API meant I didn't need to authenticate.

Sandbox org is on `Spring '19 Patch 19.4`

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

---

NOTE: I fixed this using `Named Credentials` you can read more [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260242/connect-to-salesforce-production-rest-api-from-sandbox-using-named-credentials)

Comment: Does UserInfo.getSessionId() returns valid session? Is given method called from lightning or in async mode (queueable or future)?

Comment: @kurunve it is not in a `future` or `queueable`. But `SessionID` is returning `null`.. why?

Comment: It can be due to debugs or due to the fact, that session id is not available in aura methods.

Comment: Which User is running this code?

Comment: @JayantDas a community guest user

Comment: Does the User's profile has API enabled permission set?

Comment: @JayantDas I've created a permission set with `API enabled` and added the site guest user, but I am still `null` when I call `getSessionID`

Comment: Where do you see `null`? If you are seeing that in debug logs, then you won't be able to see the value there. Debug logs do not publish this value.

Comment: @JayantDas yes it was the debug logs. But I am also getting the same error `{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}`

Comment: I used your exact code with minor changes to be able to reproduce, and I don't see any issues here. I was able to get a successful response.

Comment: @JayantDas the code is being called from a Lightning component hosted on a public community page. Did you test it in that context?

Comment: So you are using a Guest User here?

Comment: @JayantDas yes, I the code is running as the guest user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems you are using a Guest User here to be able to get a Session Id and utilize that in your code using `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());`

The error `INVALID_SESSION_ID` you are receiving is expected in that case. Refer to [**Guest user session ID returned NULL in UserInfo.getSessionId()**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000204984&type=1) knowledge article. It discusses exactly this scenario which you are facing now.

You will need to adjust the approach here as there's no workaround to get past this.

Comment: An alternative would be to use `Named Credentials` ?

Comment: @Robs You can try, I haven't really tried it out myself. But definitely `UserInfo.getSessionId()` doesn't seem to be the way here.