# Connect to Salesforce production REST API from Sandbox using Named Credentials

Tags: apex, rest-api, connected-apps, namedcredentials, auth-provider

**Background**

I would like to connect to the REST API of a production org, from a sandbox org.

Configuration so far:

1. Production Org has a `Connected App`
2. Sandbox Org has a `Auth. Provider`
3. Sandbox Org has a `Named Credential`
4. Apex code in the Sandbox org uses the `Named Credential` to access the Production Org REST API

**1. Production Org - Connected App**

- Connected App Name: `Sandbox`
- `Enable OAuth Settings` is ticked
- Callback URL: `https://x--x.cs83.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/Salesforce_REST_API` which is the sandbox
- Selected OAuth Scopes: `full refresh_token`
- `Require Secret for Web Server Flow` is ticked.
- Noted the `Key` and `Secret` for use later in the sandbox `Auth. Provider`

**2. Sandbox Org - Auth. Provider**

- Provider Type: `Salesforce`
- Name: `Salesforce Production REST API`
- URL Suffix: `Salesforce_REST_API`
- `Consumer Key` set to the key from the Production Org Connected App
- `Consumer Secret` set to the Secret from the Production Org Connected App
- `Authorize Endpoint URL` used the default value `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize`
- `Token Endpoint URL` uses the default value `https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

**3. Sandbox Org - Named Credential**

- Label: `Salesforce Production REST API`
- Name: `Salesforce_Production_REST_API`
- URL: `https://xx.my.salesforce.com` which is the production org url
- Identity Type: `Named Principle`
- Authentication Protocol: `OAuth 2.0`
- Authentication Provider: `Salesforce Production REST API` from step 2
- Scope: `full refresh_token`
- `Start Authentication Flow on Save` is ticked
- `Generate Authorization Header` is ticked
- `Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header` is ticked

Saving starts the `OAuth` process, and I successfully authenticate with my sandbox login details.

**4. Apex code in the Sandbox org uses the Named Credential**

The below code is called from a Lightning component which is running inside a publicly available community page.

```
public with sharing class ReportApi {

    private final static String REPORTS_RESOURCE = '/services/data/v44.0/analytics/reports/';

    private static HttpResponse get(String reportID) {

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        request.setEndpoint('callout:Salesforce_Production_REST_API' + REPORTS_RESOURCE + reportID);
        request.setTimeout(120000); // 2 Minutes
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');    
        request.setHeader('Content-Type',  'application/json'); 
        request.setHeader('Authorization','OAuth {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');

        HttpResponse httpResponse = new Http().send(request);

        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
HttpResponse response = ReportApi.get(reportId);
```

Yet I get this response from the production REST API:

> {"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}

When I debug the HttpRequest I get this:

> System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=callout:Salesforce_Production_REST_API/services/data/v44.0/analytics/reports/00O0O00000AYR0JUAX, Method=GET]

When I debug the HttpResponse I get this:

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]

**Question**

1. What is wrong with the above configuration?
2. How should I configure the two orgs, to allow the Sandbox Org to access the Production Org's REST API?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do so. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to include any attempts and research you've done so far.

Comment: Try changing bearer to OAuth as per the documentation

Comment: is there a reason you can't use basic authentication rather than oauth

Comment: you wouldn't need an auth provider; named credential + connected app would be good enough

Comment: You mentioned that the Apex code is called from a Lightning Component hosted in a community site. What happens with the same code from anonymous Apex in the dev console?

Comment: Under "Sandbox Org - Named Credential" you mentioned completing the oauth process with the sandbox login details. I assume you meant the production login details there.

Comment: @DanielBallinger when I run the code in anonymously I get the same error `{"message":"Session expired or
 !    invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}`

Comment: @DanielBallinger I am unable to authenticate using Production login details because the OAuth process opens `https://test.salesforce.com/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is wrong with the above configuration?

The Sandbox Org `Auth. Provider` should have been configured to use:

- Authorize Endpoint URL: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize`
- Token Endpoint URL: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

Which are the URLs for production login, allowing me to authenticate against the Production Org when using `OAuth`